# LaTeX / font-lock -- colorize bold / underline; bold; underline

Tags: emacs

I'm having trouble defining bold and underline combinations that do not conflict with each other.  A single underline trumps part of the bold and underline.  Any ideas regarding how to distinguish them so that they do not conflict?  I'd like to keep each of the LaTeX commands as separate colors.

Bold & Underline:  `{\bf\uline{insert-text}}`

Underline: `\uline{insert-text}`

[NOTE 1:  I don't use `\underline` because it cannot wrap multiple lines correctly.]

[NOTE 2:  The variable code for insert-text should also permit me to highlight certain keywords that fall within that variable code.]

[NOTE 3:  The same problem will likely happen with bold separately:  `{\bf insert-text}`]

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode (list

    (list (concat "\\(\{\\)\\(\\\\bf\\)\\(\\\\uline\\)\\(\{\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)\\(\}\\)")
        '(1 lawlist-regular t)
        '(2 lawlist-red t)
        '(3 lawlist-blue t)
        '(4 lawlist-regular t)
        '(5 lawlist-bold-underline t)
        '(7 lawlist-regular t)
        '(8 lawlist-regular t))

    (list (concat "\\(\\\\uline\\)\\(\{\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)")
        '(1 lawlist-green t)
        '(2 lawlist-regular t)
        '(3 lawlist-underline t)
        '(5 lawlist-regular t))

    lawlist-keywords

))
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Changing the definition order of `\uline{insert-text}` so that it precedes `{\bf\uline{insert-text}}` in the `init.el` may have done the trick.  I'm not sure I understand why, but it appears to work.  In other words, switching the order of the two list . . . concat definitions seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'll post an answer in the next day or so.  Order of the entries in the `init.el` matters, although I do not fully understand why that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which the entries appear will (under some circumstances) control whether subsequent entries trump prior entries.  The following example uses a specific order so that subsequent groups trump prior groups -- `lawlist-keywords` will appear highlighted within the variable text area of the LaTeX code.  The definition for the faces has not been included in this example -- those would also have to be set forth.

```
(defvar lawlist-keywords
    (list (concat "\\b\\(?:"
          (regexp-opt (list "FIXME" "TODO" "BUGS"))
          "\\)\\b") 0 'lawlist-red t))

 (font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode (list

    (list (concat "\\(\{\\)\\(\\\\bf\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)")
       '(1 lawlist-regular t)
       '(2 lawlist-purple t)
       '(3 lawlist-bold t)
       '(5 lawlist-regular t))

    (list (concat "\\(\\\\uline\\)\\(\{\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)")
        '(1 lawlist-green t)
        '(2 lawlist-regular t)
        '(3 lawlist-underline t)
        '(5 lawlist-regular t))

    (list (concat "\\(\{\\)\\(\\\\bf\\)\\(\\\\uline\\)\\(\{\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(\}\\)\\(\}\\)")
        '(1 lawlist-regular t)
        '(2 lawlist-red t)
        '(3 lawlist-blue t)
        '(4 lawlist-regular t)
        '(5 lawlist-bold-underline t)
        '(7 lawlist-regular t)
        '(8 lawlist-regular t))

    lawlist-keywords

))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your rules, you have specified 't' as the 'OVERRIDE' flag in your rules:

```
(1 lawlist-regular t)
```

The meaning of 't' is to replace the existing fontification.

Instead, try:

```
(1 larlist-regular append)
```

This will add the new fontification to the existing.

From the documentation of the Emacs variable `font-lock-keywords`:

> MATCH-HIGHLIGHT should be of the form:
>
> (SUBEXP FACENAME [OVERRIDE [LAXMATCH]])
>
> [...]
>
> OVERRIDE and LAXMATCH are flags.  If OVERRIDE is t, existing
>   fontification can be overwritten.  If `keep`, only parts not already
>   fontified are highlighted. If `prepend` or `append`, existing
>   fontification is merged with the new, in which the new or existing
>   fontification, respectively, takes precedence.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've done some experimenting with / without the `t` flag, and also by using the word `append`.  My font-lock definitions are evolving and becoming more complex in order to deal with various conflicts between similar definitions I've defined and also conflicts with the definitions contained within the AUCTeX package.  My preference at this point is to take complete control of my own definitions, to the exclusion of AUCTeX -- however, I'd like to leave that package active.  The issue in this particular thread ended up being chronological in nature -- i.e., order matters.